# Android list view to handle only Left swipes

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Currently I'm using the code present in http://www.apkbus.com/android-178853-1-1.html for handling listview swipe.It works very well for right to left swipe but I'm unable to make it work for left to right swipe. 
Your Help would be appreciated ty.
Below is the few piece of code from the example

```
public boolean onTouch(final View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if (mViewWidth < 2) {
            mViewWidth  =   mListView.getWidth();
            smallWidth  =   mViewWidth/7;
            textwidth2  =   mViewWidth/3;
            textwidth   =   textwidth2;
            largewidth  =   textwidth+textwidth2;
        }

        int tempwidth   =   0;
        if(SwipeType==1)
            tempwidth = smallWidth;
        else
            tempwidth = textwidth2;

         switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                if (mPaused) {
                    return false;
                }
                Rect rect               =   new Rect();
                int childCount          =   mListView.getChildCount();
                int[] listViewCoords    = new int[2];
                mListView.getLocationOnScreen(listViewCoords);
                int x                   = (int) event.getRawX() - listViewCoords[0];
                int y                   = (int) event.getRawY() - listViewCoords[1];
                ViewGroup child;
                for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                    child = (ViewGroup) mListView.getChildAt(i);
                    child.getHitRect(rect);
                    if (rect.contains(x, y)) {
                        mDownView_parent    =   child;
                        mDownView           =   (ViewGroup) child.findViewById(R.id.list_display_view_container);
                        if(mDownView_parent.getChildCount()==1){
                            textheight  =   mDownView_parent.getHeight();
                            if(SwipeType==Dismiss){
                                HalfColor       =   singleColor;
                                HalfDrawable    =   activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.content_discard);
                            }
                           SetBackGroundforList();
                        }


                        if(old_mDownView!=null && mDownView!=old_mDownView){
                            ResetListItem(old_mDownView);
                            old_mDownView=null;
                            return false;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (mDownView != null) {
                    mDownX              =   event.getRawX();
                    mDownPosition       =   mListView.getPositionForView(mDownView);
                    mVelocityTracker    =   VelocityTracker.obtain();
                    mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
                } else {
                    mDownView               =   null;
                }

                //mSwipeDetected              =   false;
                temp_position               =   mListView.pointToPosition((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
                view.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
                    break;
                }
                float deltaX                =   event.getRawX() - mDownX;
                mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
                mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000); // 1000 by defaut but
                float velocityX             =   mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity();                                            // it was too much
                float absVelocityX          =   Math.abs(velocityX);
                float absVelocityY          =   Math.abs(mVelocityTracker.getYVelocity());
                boolean swipe               =   false;
                boolean swipeRight          =   false;

                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > tempwidth) {
                    swipe               =   true;
                    swipeRight          =   deltaX > 0;

                }else if (mMinFlingVelocity <= absVelocityX && absVelocityX <= mMaxFlingVelocity && absVelocityY < absVelocityX) {
                    // dismiss only if flinging in the same direction as dragging
                    swipe   = (velocityX < 0) == (deltaX < 0);
                    swipeRight          = mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity() > 0;
                }

                if (deltaX < 0 && swipe) {
                    mListView.setDrawSelectorOnTop(false);

                    if (swipe && !swipeRight && deltaX <= -tempwidth) {
                        FullSwipeTrigger();
                    } else if (deltaX >= -textwidth && SwipeType==Double) {
                        ResetListItem(mDownView);
                    }else {
                        ResetListItem(mDownView);
                    }
                } else {
                    ResetListItem(mDownView);
                }

                mVelocityTracker.recycle();
                mVelocityTracker    =   null;
                mDownX              =   0;
                mDownView           =   null;
                mDownPosition       =   ListView.INVALID_POSITION;
                mSwiping            =   false;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

                float deltaX = event.getRawX() - mDownX;
                if (mVelocityTracker == null || mPaused ||deltaX>0) {
                    break;
                }

                mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);


                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > mSlop) {
                    mSwiping = true;
                    mListView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                    // Cancel ListView's touch (un-highlighting the item)
                    MotionEvent cancelEvent     =   MotionEvent.obtain(event);
                    cancelEvent.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL |
                            (event.getActionIndex()
                                    << MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT));
                    mListView.onTouchEvent(cancelEvent);
                    cancelEvent.recycle();
                }
                if (mSwiping && deltaX < 0 ) {

                    int width;
                    if(SwipeType==1){
                        width   =   textwidth;
                    }
                    else{
                        width   =   largewidth;
                    }

                    if (-deltaX<width){
                        mDownView.setTranslationX(deltaX);
                        return false;
                    }
                    return false;
                }else if(mSwiping){
                    ResetListItem(mDownView);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Refer: http://www.tutecentral.com/android-swipe-listview/

Comment: @VibhorChopra That tutorial is great, but since I have already implemented the above code, I would like to use the same existing code for left to right swiping.